# Codeigniter Extracting Data From Database With Function

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have to extract two separate pieces of information from my mysql database. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to extract two different sets of information via function(s) I'm writing. I'm trying to figure out a solution but I'm not getting it. Below is my syntax so far. My goal here is to get both of the functions (getPrice and getOtherPrice) all within the same function working. If I // one, the other one works. If both are active, just one is working. How would you guys go about correcting this issue, what do you think I'm doing wrong? Thanks Everyone.

```
function getJoinInformation($year,$make,$model)
{
$data = $this->getPrice($year,$make,$model);
$data = $this->getOtherPrice($year,$make,$model);
return $data;    
}

function getPrice($year,$make,$model)
{
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tbl_car_description d');
 $this->db->join('tbl_car_prices p', 'd.id = p.cardescription_id');
 $this->db->where('d.year', $year);
 $this->db->where('d.make', $make);
 $this->db->where('d.model', $model);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
}

function getOtherPrice($year,$make,$model)
{
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tbl_car_description d');
 $this->db->where('d.year', $year);
 $this->db->where('d.make', $make);
 $this->db->where('d.model', $model);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? Message and more Details (Linenumber etc.) would be usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are returning only last function result you should put the the result of both function by making an array of `$data`

```
function getJoinInformation($year,$make,$model)
{
$data['getPrice'] = $this->getPrice($year,$make,$model);
$data['getOtherPrice'] = $this->getOtherPrice($year,$make,$model);
return $data;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the result in the variable $data.

```
$data = $this->getPrice($year,$make,$model);
$data = $this->getOtherPrice($year,$make,$odel);
```

$data will always just contain the result of the last function.